# PHP analogue of MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I need write php function calculating  hash from password string.
In MSSQL hash is calculated like:

```
lower(substring(convert(varchar(200), hashbytes('md5', 'my_password_string' + '|' + cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar(max))), 1), 3, 32))
```

What is php analogue of this crazy algorithm?

I tried this:

```
$password = hash('md5' , 'my_password_string'.'|'.date('YYYY-mm-dd'), false);
```

but result is not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `hash()`, but the important parts are 1) the result of the date conversion, 2) the character encoding of the password and 3) the `varchar` collation of the data in the database. But the following basic example is an option:

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   LOWER(SUBSTRING(
      CONVERT(
         varchar(200),
         HASHBYTES(
            'md5', 
            'my_password_string' + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 23))
         ),
         1
      ),
      3,
      32
   ))
```

PHP:

```
<?
$password = strtolower(substr(hash('md5' , 'my_password_string'.'|'.date('Y-m-d'), false), 0, 200));
echo $password;
?>
```

Result:

```
b2b2c0a81c42f802d98200daa504f197
```

Comment: Thanks, Zhorow ! I used other format for datetime.  Your format is ok!